# Displaying NSMenuItem in SwiftUI on it's own

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have been trying to display a custom NSMenuItem (for a preview page of a menu manager) inside a SwiftUI view. But I can't achieve it. I have figured it needs to wrapped inside a menu first, and thought that there might be a way to pop the menu pragmatically but sadly, those efforts have failed and the app crashes.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct NSMenuItemView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
            let view = NSView()
            let menu = NSMenu()
            let item = menu.addItem(withTitle: "Do Action", action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
            item.target = context.coordinator
            view.menu = menu
            return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSView, context: Context) {
        // App crashes here :/ 
        view.menu?.popUpMenuPositioningItem(
            positioning: view.menu?.item(at: 0),
            at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            in: view
        )
    }
}

extension NSMenuItemView {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: NSMenuItemView
    
        init(_ parent: NSMenuItemView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        @objc
        func valueChanged(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Is it even possible to just pragmatically display NSMenuItem?

The NSMenu comfors to NSViewRepresentable so I figured it might just workout, and have seen answers on StackOverflow (granted date a while back) showing similar code that should work.

Without the `popUpMenuPositioningItem` it works - in a way I guess - when I right click in the View, the MenuItem Appears. But I would like to be able to display the menu without the right click, just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the menu is shown while the view are still rendering so that the crash happens. To avoid this you should call `popUp(positioning:at:in)` after the your view appears on the screen. The way to achieve it, we have to use publisher to trigger an event to show menu inside `onAppear` modifier and listen it inside `Coordinator`. Here is the sample for that solution.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let menuPopUpTrigger = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            NSMenuItemView(menuPopUpTrigger)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            /// trigger an event when `onAppear` is executed
            menuPopUpTrigger.send()
        }
    }
}

struct NSMenuItemView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let base = NSView()
    let menu = NSMenu()
    
    var menuPopUpTrigger: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
    
    init(_ menuPopUpTrigger: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>) {
        self.menuPopUpTrigger = menuPopUpTrigger
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let item = menu.addItem(withTitle: "Do Action", action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        item.target = context.coordinator
        base.menu = menu
        context.coordinator.bindTrigger(menuPopUpTrigger)
        return base
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSView, context: Context) { }
}

extension NSMenuItemView {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: NSMenuItemView
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
        init(_ parent: NSMenuItemView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: NSMenuItem) { }
        
        /// bind trigger to listen an event
        func bindTrigger(_ trigger: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>) {
            cancellable = trigger
                .delay(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                .sink { [weak self] in
                    self?.parent.menu.popUp(
                        positioning: self?.parent.menu.item(at: 0),
                        at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                        in: self?.parent.base
                    )
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you to get what you want.